# can we View the contents of the atop log files that sent from remote machine on local machine

Tags: linux, rhel, performance, top, atop

on remote machine we have the following atop files

```
ls -l /var/log/atop/
total 1634632
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 127992086 Aug 30 01:49 atop_20180829
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 262277153 Aug 31 00:00 atop_20180830
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 321592670 Sep  1 00:00 atop_20180831
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 330041977 Sep  2 00:00 atop_20180901
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 269040388 Sep  3 00:00 atop_20180902
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 274807097 Sep  4 00:00 atop_20180903
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  85426960 Sep  4 06:03 atop_20180904
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root         0 Sep  4 06:03 daily.log
```

we get the log - atop_20180904

and we want to put it on our local machine under /var/log/atop

can we test it ( view the log ) as:

```
 atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_20180904
```

inspite this log created on other machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly view the imported `atop` log file on another machine that runs `atop` as `atop` run it's own binary format and each file is a self-contained statistics repository/DB on its own.

You may also see it directly from a remote machine doing:

```
ssh remote_machine "sudo atop -r /var/log/atop/atop_20180904"
```

Ultimately if you want to monitor on the log term several Unix servers, it might be more practical on the term to monitor them via SNMP with something as [Cacti](https://www.cacti.net/).

Comment: thank you , for this info , another question please , as you know atop is one of several tools , do you think it is the one of the best tools that we can installed on our linux to view performance ?

Comment: It depends on want are your goals and how many machines you want to view. You have got many tools. If we are talking about `local` tools, I actually prefer sar. In corporate environments, I ran Nagios+SNMPagents.